# Populate TextBox's value to a specific Textbox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox

I have three TextBoxe1,TextBoxe2 and TextBoxe3 and one main TextBox4 and Button1 when its clicked it will insert TextBox4's value into the clicked (the chosen/selected/clicked one) TextBox. This code Populates all the TextBoxes with the same value.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox[] array = new TextBox[3] { textBox1, textBox2, textBox3 };
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            if (array[i].Focus())
            {
                array[i].Text = textBox4.Text;
            }
        }

    }
```

[image]

But I want it to take the TextBox4's value and insert into the TextBox2 that I have Clicked on. Like this illu.:

[image]

Comment: Handle the click event for each textbox, and set a class level member to the clicked textbox object. When you click the button, just use that member to change the textbox value. If you used the `object sender` parameter from the event handler, you could do this with only 1 click handler for all 3 textboxes.

Comment: Doesn’t .focus() set the focus to the control?

Comment: @Hursey That's an affirmative.

Comment: @Hursey, No it doesn't.

Comment: @CrownFord That contradicts [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.focus?view=netframework-4.7.2): "The following code example sets focus to the specified Control, if it can receive focus." - the boolean result indicates if it was able to set focus. Note that by clicking the button, you're removing the focus from textbox, so even if `.Focus()` indicated the focus state, it would indicate that it isn't focused.

Comment: Could try form.activecontrol

Comment: When you click on the button, the button will be the active control not the text box.

Comment: @John, How to fix it?

Comment: I think you wanted to check for the [Focused](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.focused?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Forms_Control_Focused) property. But it won't help you anyway, because of the reasons described by @RezaAghaei

Comment: @RezaAghaei What do you suggest to change in the code?

Comment: @CrownFord You could try my suggestion in my first comment.

Comment: @John, I did, but no luck

Comment: It's better to change the way that you set the value for those `TextBox` controls. It's not good idea to rely on the last selected text box. Anyway, if you like to keep it this way, define a field in form, `TextBox selectedTextBox;`, then handle `Enter` event of those 3 `TextBox` controls and in the handler set `selectedTextBox = (TextBox)sender`. Then  in `Click` event handler of the button, set `selectedTextBox.Text = textBox4.Text;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better to change the way that you set the value for those `TextBox` controls and think about another UI, but anyway, if you like to keep it as is, I'll share an idea to satisfy the requirement which you described in the question.

Define a field in form, `TextBox selectedTextBox;`, then handle `Enter` event of those 3 `TextBox` controls and in the handler set `selectedTextBox = (TextBox)sender`. Then  in `Click` event handler of the button, check if `selectedTextBox` is not null, then set `selectedTextBox.Text = textBox4.Text;`:

```
TextBox selectedTextBox;
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    textBox1.Enter += TextBox_Enter;
    textBox2.Click += TextBox_Enter;
    textBox3.Click += TextBox_Enter;

    button1.Click += button1_Click;
}

void TextBox_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    selectedTextBox = (TextBox)sender;
}
void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(selectedTextBox!=null)
        selectedTextBox.Text = textBox4.Text;
}
```

Make sure you don't attach event handler twice, so to attach event handler, use code editor or designer, not both of them.

Comment: @ Reza Aghaei Works great same way I wanted. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Register the `Click` event of the 3 target `TextBox`es to the same handler:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    textBox1.Click += TransportValueEvent_Click;
    textBox2.Click += TransportValueEvent_Click;
    textBox3.Click += TransportValueEvent_Click;
}
```

Inside the handler get the `sender` (which will be the TextBox that you have clicked) as `TextBox` and write the value:

```
private void TransportValueEvent_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    (sender as TextBox).Text = textBox4.Text;
}
```

Now you don't need the button anymore. The value will be written to the correct TextBox as soon as you click it.

May be you want to avoid deletion if the `textBox4` is empty, then you can update the value only if:

```
private void TransportValueEvent_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox4.Text))
    {
        (sender as TextBox).Text = textBox4.Text;
    }
}
```